# Why is this one paragraph link showing up funky?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, href

I am attaching some code in here, I have recently added in a link to my portfolio website and the paragraph link is doing something weird, it seems to be aligning funky and I'm not sure what the issue is. I'm wondering if it might be stemming from some other a stylings in the CSS (like nav_links) but I'm unsure how to correct this without messing up the other a stylings.

I added a class to the a href and tried to add in some CSS styling for it, it fixed some issues (like the size and color)but that gap

Comment: Clarify your question again? What actually you want to do with this code. and what's gone wrong....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making a mistake in your CSS, doing things like this:

```css
.nav_link li, a
```

You need to remove those commas. I assume here you're trying to style an `a` within an `li` within an element with a class of `.nav_link`. But that's NOT what you're doing. Instead, this selector is applying a bunch of styles to `.nav_link li` and *separately* to all `a` elements. The selector should actually read like so:

```css
.nav_link li a
```

You have this issue at several points in your CSS.

Comment: I removed that comma and now the styling of the links doesn't work anymore on my website. 

I'll try to attach a photo

Comment: Yes, I had a feeling it would break things, but it's a good opportunity to iron out your CSS now that that bug of the comma has been removed. It's painful, but better than endless pain down the track.

Comment: Thanks Ralph! I think I fixed it. I'll send my CSS Code here. This was a big help, it definitely helped me identify some things. 

Though the commas are still in location in some places.

Comment: @BigFir — Glad it was of help. :-)

Comment: Thanks again! I'm doing this in my other projects and it's been a great help.

Answer (score 0):

Rereading your question I'm not sure exactly what problem you're trying to solve. What do you mean by "aligning funky"?

The CSS on the "design portfolio" has `float: left` and margins.

`float: left` takes it out of the flow and moves it to the left of the viewport, and causes the other text (e.g. "reading a book") to wrap around it (and its margins).

```css
.nav_link li, a {
    display: inline;
    float: left; /* <------ this */
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: "neue-haas-grotesk-display", sans-serif;
    margin-left: 16px; /* <------ and this */
    margin-top: 24px; /* <------ and this */
    margin-bottom: 36px; /* <------ and this */
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #f8f8f8;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use this style for your link element under the paragraph.

`.hero_text p a { display: inline-block; float: none; margin: 0px; }`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the help! The issue looked to be the comma. In a previous thread I read here or perhaps elsewhere, I saw that I should be adding in commas in order to change the styling of text in a certain div – but it appears that the comma was the issue.

I'd like to also learn about if there is an instance where a comma comes into play in CSS.

Thanks for your help! I have corrected that issue and cleaned up the rest of my navigation and text; This helped me to learn more about the text styling and how it displays and also a bit more about flexbox.

I forget how to close this out but this has been fixed!

Comment: You should avoid writing thank you comments as an answer.